# Nested for loop with step not working

Tags: vba, for-loop

I have the following code. As you can see for next with step loops. The two inner loops are working okay, but the outer loop is not running at all. It appears to be something with how I'm "dim" ing the variables, but honestly I'm not sure why this isn't working. To simplify I deleted some of the code within the inner loop but I don't think that will affect the for next loops.

```
Sub AlgorithmOptimizertest()

    Dim PBmin As Double
    Dim PBmax As Double
    Dim PBstep As Double
    Dim PRORmin As Double
    Dim PRORmax As Double
    Dim PRORstep As Double

    Dim ROEmin As Double
    Dim ROEmax As Double
    Dim ROEstep As Double

    PBmin = Sheets("ModelSummary").Range("AP6").Value
    PBmax = Sheets("ModelSummary").Range("AP7").Value
    PBstep = Sheets("ModelSummary").Range("AP8").Value
    PRORmin = Sheets("ModelSummary").Range("AO6").Value
    PRORmax = Sheets("ModelSummary").Range("AO7").Value
    PRORstep = Sheets("ModelSummary").Range("AO8").Value
    ROEmin = Sheets("ModelSummary").Range("AD6").Value
    ROEmax = Sheets("ModelSummary").Range("AD7").Value
    ROEstep = Sheets("ModelSummary").Range("AD8").Value

    For k = ROEmin To ROEmax Step ROEstep
        Range("AD5").Value = k
        For j = PRORmin To PRORmax Step PRORstep
            Range("AO5").Value = j
            For i = PBmin To PBmax Step PBstep
                Range("AP5").Value = i

                Call PorfolioBuilder

            Next i
        Next j   
    Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you verified that the value in AD8 (when added to AD6) doesn't exceed the value in AD7, thus executing the loop once only?  I assume the outermost loop executes at least once, since you say the inner loops are working fine.

Comment: This code would benefit from a big 'ole [With ... End With statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) that defined the *ModelSummary* worksheet around all of the code. Are you selecting, activating or creating another worksheet in PorfolioBuilder?

Comment: What are the values of ROEmin, ROEmax and ROEstep?

Answer (score 0):

it is definitively not a code problem. 
It could something to do with your data in the cells.

But to be accurate you should do something like this:

```
dim wb as workbook, ws as worksheet
'put your dim's here

set wb=thisworkbook
set ws=wb.worksheets("ModelSummary")

'read your values here
ROEmin = ws.Range("AD6").Value
'also you might want to try this
'ROEMIN = ws.Cells(ws.Range("AD6").row,ws.Range("AD6").column)

'then call your loops
For k = ROEmin To ROEmax Step ROEstep
    Range("AD5").Value = k
    For j = PRORmin To PRORmax Step PRORstep
        Range("AO5").Value = j
        For i = PBmin To PBmax Step PBstep
            Range("AP5").Value = i

            Call PorfolioBuilder

        Next i
    Next j   
Next k
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  i will try defining the workbook.  To add to the  problem statement, the code works for some sets of ranges, but not others.  For example, it works if I set the ROEmin at 0.5 and the max at 1 with a step of 0.1.  But it doesn't work if min is set at 0.8 and the max is 1 with a step of 0.1.  It also works if I set the max a little bit above where I really want it to be.  So if I want the max to be 1.2, then I set the max used in the loop to be 1.21 with a step of 0.1 and it works.

Comment: So it does appear to be a problem with the data in the cells.